# Failure using ilasm, but no reason given

Tags: .net, compilation, ilasm

I am trying to use `ILASM` and the process seems to abort with the following message:

```
***** FAILURE *****
```

How can I find out why it has failed?  Can I turn on verbose messages or is there a log file I can look at?

Comment: Type `echo %errorlevel%` to get the exit code.

Comment: That returned `1`. What does that mean?

Comment: Nothing useful unfortunately.

Comment: Did you figured out this issue? Am running through same problem

Answer (score 8):

While I realise that this is probably too late to help the question author now, I will leave these details here in case it helps someone in the future.

I had a similar problem recently where `Ildasm` would enable me to disassemble some DLLs to ILs, but `Ilasm` would *not* let me reassemble them into DLLs. Like the question author, my console output was very unhelpful, just stating:

```
***** FAILURE *****
```

But without any reasons listed.

In my case, it was a simple error, where I had copied my Strong Name Key file into the wrong directory. After I realised and put it into the correct location, `Ilasm` could access it successfully and was therefore able to reassemble my DLLs.

I think that it is a real shame that this basic error wasn't mentioned in an error output... it's one of the first things that I could think had gone wrong... or maybe that's why it wasn't listed... because it was easily fixed?

---

UPDATE >>>

One way that you can tell if you have this exact problem or not, is to look at the Console Window output... with no valid Strong Name Key file, `Ilasm` stops at the end of the *Assembled method ...* section, eg. *every* line will have the following (or similar) on it:

```
Assembled method Namespace.SubNamespace.ClassName::MethodName
```

If your output has the following lines in it then you probably have a different problem to this one as it should be missing from the output when there is no Strong Name Key file:

```
Creating PE file   

Emitting classes:
```

Comment: Another cause is if you're trying to use a .pfx file instead of a .snk for the key. [This article](http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com/2009/12/adding-strong-name-to-third-party.html) shows how to get .snk from .pfx: `SN -p MyCertificate.pfx MyCertificate-publickey.snk`

Comment: You just saved my day Sir!

Answer (score 1):

ilasm output so many crap info, just redirect them.

run 'ilasm.exe ..... > 1.txt', you will see the truth.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for failure when I ran ilasm.exe was that folder names included in the path to the .il file contained spaces.

Placing double quotes around the entire path is the solution.